# How to install Line 6 Kb 37 in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a good way to install [Line 6 TonePort KB37](http://line6.com/legacy/toneportkb37)?

So that it functions for monitoring, Recording would be nice too but not as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First open your Terminal

You will need to get Subversion

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Then you will need to get the source

```
svn co https://line6linux.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/line6linux
```

Change to the directory

```
cd line6linux/driver/trunk
```

Time to build from the source but first make sure you have the latest build and headers

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install linux-headers
```

Now that is updated and you are in the trunk directory

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now shutdown and restart with the guitar port (or toneport) connected and you should be able to see it.

[source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-a-line6-guitarport-or-toneport-ux1-or-gx.html)